# Prevent correction from collision between multiple AABBs from tricking itself

Tags: javascript, algorithm, collision-detection, collision, game-physics

I'm making a physics engine for a game that uses collisions between AABBs (Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes). The collision is checked and resolved for every possible pair of AABBs (n(O^2) complexity), and they can be either static or dynamic, so collisions may happen between bodies:

- dynamic vs static
- dynamic vs dynamic

I already managed to make it work, but in some cases the collision solver tricks itself.

[image: A red box falls over a static green box, and another red box falls over it, making the first pass through the green one]

This happens because the first red AABB to collide with the green one gets it's position corrected by the second red AABB to a position where it's inside the green ground, after the ground checks for collisions, so no check is made anymore. This is a simple demonstration which gets more and more complex as boxes stack up.

[Here's](http://sketchtoy.com/66686614) a drawing that demonstrates how this problem works.

I'll post my entire algorithm, but notice that it will be easier if you follow the second chunk of code first to understand the code better.

**Here's the collision-related part:**

```
class Collision {
    static hasIntersection (bodyA, bodyB) {
        if (bodyA.y + bodyA.height > bodyB.y &&
            bodyA.x + bodyA.width  > bodyB.x &&
            bodyA.x < bodyB.x + bodyB.width  &&
            bodyA.y < bodyB.y + bodyB.height) 
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    static getAxisCollisions (bodyA, bodyB) {
        var collisions = [];
        if (bodyA.py + bodyA.height <= bodyB.py &&
            bodyA.y + bodyA.height > bodyB.y) {
            collisions.push("top");
        }
        if (bodyA.px + bodyA.width <= bodyB.px &&
            bodyA.x + bodyA.width > bodyB.x) {
            collisions.push("left");
        }
        if (bodyA.px >= bodyB.px + bodyB.width &&
            bodyA.x < bodyB.x + bodyB.width) {
            collisions.push("right");
        }
        if (bodyA.py >= bodyB.py + bodyB.height &&
            bodyA.y < bodyB.y + bodyB.height) {
            collisions.push("bottom");
        }
        return collisions;
    }
    static getCollisionNormal (bodyA, bodyB) {
        if (bodyA.static) return {
                top: bodyA.bottom,
                left: bodyA.right,
                right: bodyA.left,
                bottom: bodyA.top
            };
        else if (bodyB.static) return {
                top: bodyB.top,
                left: bodyB.left,
                right: bodyB.right,
                bottom: bodyB.bottom
            };
        else return {
            top: (bodyA.bottom * bodyA.mass + bodyB.top * bodyB.mass) / (bodyA.mass + bodyB.mass),
            left: (bodyA.right * bodyA.mass + bodyB.left * bodyB.mass) / (bodyA.mass + bodyB.mass),
            right: (bodyA.left * bodyA.mass + bodyB.right * bodyB.mass) / (bodyA.mass + bodyB.mass),
            bottom: (bodyA.top * bodyA.mass + bodyB.bottom * bodyB.mass) / (bodyA.mass + bodyB.mass)
        };
    }
    static getVelocityNormal (bodyA, bodyB) {
        var vx = (bodyA.vx * bodyA.mass + bodyB.vx * bodyB.mass) / (bodyA.mass + bodyB.mass),
            vy = (bodyA.vy * bodyA.mass + bodyB.vy * bodyB.mass) / (bodyA.mass + bodyB.mass);
        return bodyA.static ? {vx: bodyA.vx, vy: bodyA.vy} :
               bodyB.static ? {vx: bodyB.vx, vy: bodyB.vy} :
               {vx, vy};
    }
    static resolveSideCollision (bodyA, bodyB, side) {
        var collisionNormal = this.getCollisionNormal(bodyA, bodyB);
        var velocityNormal = this.getVelocityNormal(bodyA, bodyB);

        switch (side) {
            case "top":
                bodyA.y = collisionNormal.top - bodyA.height;
                bodyB.y = collisionNormal.top;

                bodyA.vy = bodyB.vy = velocityNormal.vy;
            break;
            case "left":
                bodyA.x = collisionNormal.left - bodyA.width;
                bodyB.x = collisionNormal.left;
                bodyA.vx = bodyB.vx = velocityNormal.vx;
            break;
            case "right":
                bodyA.x = collisionNormal.right;
                bodyB.x = collisionNormal.right - bodyB.width;
                bodyA.vx = bodyB.vx = velocityNormal.vx;
            break;
            case "bottom":
                bodyA.y = collisionNormal.bottom;
                bodyB.y = collisionNormal.bottom - bodyB.height;
                bodyA.vy = bodyB.vy = velocityNormal.vy;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**...And how it's being used inside the physics world every frame (which is a method in the PhysicsWorld class):**

```
step () {
    var i, i1, i2, i3, body, bodyA, bodyB, iterations = 0, hadCollisions = false;
    for (i = 0; i < this.dynamicBodies.length; ++i) {
        body = this.dynamicBodies[i];

        if (body.affectedByGravity) body.vy += 0.25;

        body.px = body.x;
        body.py = body.y;
        body.x += body.vx;
        body.y += body.vy;
    }
    do {
        ++iterations;
        hadCollisions = false;
        for (i1 = 0; i1 < this.bodies.length; ++i1) {
            bodyA = this.bodies[i1];
            for (i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < this.bodies.length; ++i2) {
                bodyB = this.bodies[i2];

                if (Collision.hasIntersection(bodyA, bodyB)) {
                    hadCollisions = true;
                    var axises = Collision.getAxisCollisions(bodyA, bodyB);
                    if (axises.length === 1) { // Collisions with multiple side are treated as edge collisions
                        Collision.resolveSideCollision(bodyA, bodyB, axises[0], iterations);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (i1 = 0; i1 < this.bodies.length; ++i1) {
            bodyA = this.bodies[i1];
            for (i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < this.bodies.length; ++i2) {
                bodyB = this.bodies[i2];

                if (Collision.hasIntersection(bodyA, bodyB)) {
                    hadCollisions = true;
                    var axises = Collision.getAxisCollisions(bodyA, bodyB);

                    for(i3 = 0; i3 < axises.length; ++i3){
                        Collision.resolveSideCollision(bodyA, bodyB, axises[0], iterations);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } while (hadCollisions && iterations < 0); // If iterations are large enough, things stop going wrong and stacking objects is somewhat possible, if their mass is not too different.
}
```

You can also see the entire project on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/TiagoMarinho/Lab-Cat/tree/master/Custom%20Physics).

Important notes:

- `body.py` means the `y` position in the last frame, as well as `body.px` means the past x position.
- `body.vy` means the velocity in the `y` axis, as well as `body.vx` means the velocity in the `x` axis.
- the origin is placed on the top left corner of the physics bodies.

Comment: Sorry, didn't look into your code in detail, but I know that in such simulations it is important to know how much the two objects overlap, the bigger the overlap the higher is the force, which try to push those objects apart from each other. I think the information whether two object overlap may be not enough.

Comment: @ead collisions are resolved using the equation `(bodyA.bottom * bodyA.mass + bodyB.top * bodyB.mass) / (bodyA.mass + bodyB.mass)` for collisions between bodyA's bottom and bodyB's top side, for example. This equation takes into account how much they overlap, and separates them depending on their mass.

Comment: normally, the the forces from all collitions are added up and the resulting force is applied to the object. In your code the last collision "wins": If the collision between small boxes is resolved as the last, then the small box in the middle will always be pushed downwards (If I understand it right).

Comment: @ead Mmm right, just not force but position. What would you recommend me to do to solve this prevalence problem then?

Comment: You could try to accumulated the changes for a box from collisions with all other boxes and only then resolve the collisions. But than, at least for some time, overlapping between boxes would be possible (elastic collision). If you need inelastic collision maybe http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5906/collision-resolution could help you

Comment: @ead supposing I have a collisions between three objects like in the above example, I can't understand how do you think the resolution would work for all the three at the same time. Could you develop that into an actual answer? Also, the answer in your link provides information about collisions between circles, which I don't think that can improve my current algorithm.